# Detail the required score on the "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym" error

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, error-message

When trying to upvote a tag synonym without the required score on the master tag, the following error is displayed:

> *You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym*

I propose changing it to:

> *You must have an answer score of 5 or more on the [browser-cache](/questions/tagged/browser-cache) tag to vote for this tag synonym*

I'm referring to this error:

[image: req]

Comment: Doesn't it already say that *directly* above there? If anything it should say "Please read the paragraph directly above this."

Comment: @animuson To be honest, I've only just seen that now that you've pointed it out. I'm used to just performing the actions I want, and if something goes wrong, scanning the page for the reason why. The error message was the only place I looked. Idk, I just don't see why this error should be "dumber" than the others, and I'm probably not the only person to search Meta for the required score. I do too many things at once to read every bit of blocks of text :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree that saying "you don't have the required score" is pretty useless, and of course someone who doesn't know what the required score is will be confused because you didn't tell them. There's no need to include the actual name of the tag in the notification, though. You're on the tag's synonym page, you should know what tag we're referring to.

I say just replace "the required score" with "a score of 5 or more" so it reads:

> You do not have a score of 5 or more on this tag to vote for this tag synonym

Quick and simple and ya... Because I'm sure no one is actually reading that paragraph of text... It's a paragraph... and as far as I'm aware, the score of 5 thing doesn't change across different sites, only the reputation requirement does. So there's really no reason that can't be included in a non-dynamic error message.

Comment: Another question is why we should need "a score of 5 or more" to decide whether browser-chache and browser-caching are similar.